# How can I remove duplicates in PowerPivot?

Tags: powerpivot

I have a PowerPivot opened in Excel that's loading a csv file.
I need to remove duplicates in a column but there is no query edit.
What's the best way to do this?
The column in question contains text values like addresses

Comment: Can you pass it through Power Query first to remove duplicates and then load it to the Power Pivot data model?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, you can use power query (part of excel 2016, addonn in excel 2013) to clean the data up before it is loaded into power pivot.  Note that if you are using power query it is case sensitive so it will consider ABC <> Abc.

It does have functions to force strings to be all upper case, lower case or Capital for the first word.

The option is to setup the connection in Power Pivot, then go to the loaded table in the model.  In the ribbon do design --> Table properties which has options for editing the SQL statement which is used to generate the table.